# Tabulator not working with remote pagination and ajaxURLGenerator

Tags: javascript, ajax, pagination, tabulator

I have an issue with tabulator (4.9.1) and the pagination, when I try to configure it with remote pagination and ajaxUrlGenerator function, it never pass into the generator function, after investigating the code I've noticed that the code of tabulator do the following :

```js
Tabulator.prototype._loadInitialData = function () {
    var self = this;

    if (self.options.pagination && self.modExists("page")) {
        self.modules.page.reset(true, true);

        if (self.options.pagination == "local") {
            if (self.options.data.length) {
                self.rowManager.setData(self.options.data, false, true);
            } else {
                if ((self.options.ajaxURL || self.options.ajaxURLGenerator) && self.modExists("ajax")) {
                    self.modules.ajax.loadData(false, true).then(function () {}).catch(function () {
                        if (self.options.paginationInitialPage) {
                            self.modules.page.setPage(self.options.paginationInitialPage);
                        }
                    });

                    return;
                } else {
                    self.rowManager.setData(self.options.data, false, true);
                }
            }

            if (self.options.paginationInitialPage) {
                self.modules.page.setPage(self.options.paginationInitialPage);
            }
        } else {
            if (self.options.ajaxURL) {
                self.modules.page.setPage(self.options.paginationInitialPage).then(function () {}).catch(function () {});
            } else {
                self.rowManager.setData([], false, true);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (self.options.data.length) {
            self.rowManager.setData(self.options.data);
        } else {
            if ((self.options.ajaxURL || self.options.ajaxURLGenerator) && self.modExists("ajax")) {
                self.modules.ajax.loadData(false, true).then(function () {}).catch(function () {});
            } else {
                self.rowManager.setData(self.options.data, false, true);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

using the ajaxURLGenerator with the 'local' configuration makes it work correctly in remote.
But then it doesn't do the progressive pagination and doesn't pass the parameters correctly in the ajaxURLGenerator function, probably due to the parsing mecanism that is not called in 'local' mode for the data :

```js
Page.prototype.trigger = function () {
    var _this81 = this;

    var left;

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        switch (_this81.mode) {
            case "local":
                left = _this81.table.rowManager.scrollLeft;

                _this81.table.rowManager.refreshActiveData("page");
                _this81.table.rowManager.scrollHorizontal(left);

                _this81.table.options.pageLoaded.call(_this81.table, _this81.getPage());
                resolve();
                break;

            case "remote":
            case "progressive_load":
            case "progressive_scroll":
                _this81.table.modules.ajax.blockActiveRequest();
                _this81._getRemotePage().then(function () {
                    resolve();
                }).catch(function () {
                    reject();
                });
                break;

            default:
                console.warn("Pagination Error - no such pagination mode:", _this81.mode);
                reject();
        }
    });
};
```

At the end it is loading, but all the data when the server return just a json list, but it fail when receiving the object expected for the remote pagination.
Does anyone had the same issue with remote pagination and ajaxURLGenerator? Anyone has an idea how to solve it, without modifying the library?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post a link to a JS fiddle that demonstrates your issue, we need to see how your table is configured to point you at the correct answer.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer, sadly I had some difficulties to reproduce it on jsfiddle because of the ajaxUrl, but at least the code should be identical.
The working version on my computer (the pagination is failing but it start loading) : [jsFiddle local pagination as remote](https://jsfiddle.net/Nitnek/tsd3mq2o/3/)

The expected implementation based on the documentation : 
[jsFiddle expected config remote pagination](https://jsfiddle.net/Nitnek/vkcmd3w4/88/)

If you need more data or a locally running example, tell me.

Thanks again